# Why does starting a new Android activity in Kotlin require a Java class?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

If I want to start a new Activity in Android, I need to pass the Activity to an Intent. However, instead of just passing the Kotlin class like so:

```
val intent: Intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class)
```

I need to pass the Kotlin class as a Java class like this:

```
val intent: Intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
```

Why do I need to add this extra identifier since my `SearchActivity` is a .kt file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second parameter to the `Intent` constructor that you are using takes a `java.lang.Class` object. `SearchActivity::class` returns a `kotlin.reflect.KClass`. You get a `java.lang.Class` from that by accessing [its `java` property](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html). Hence, you wind up with the somewhat odd syntax of `SearchActivity::class.java`.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's an explanation](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/java-vs-kotlin-class-78feec0c3d0e).

Basically, `ClassName::class` returns *Kotlin's* implementation of Class, KClass, which doesn't extend Java's Class. That's why `::class.java` is needed. `java` is a getter in KClass, which returns a Java Class version of the KClass instance.

Check out the [KClass Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/index.html).